# Typing localhost is redirecting to another host in ubuntu

Tags: networking

When I am typing `localhost` in my browser it is automatically redirecting to another site for eg `google.com`. Can someone please tell me how this is happening and can I change this behaviour?

Comment: What is in your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: this is because your default search setting is google.com and your localhost server is unavailable check out oli's answer it is correct I also have same string when I just type local host in my browser window

Comment: What's your browser?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that *some* browsers consider the input as a search string if they don't recognise the domain name format. This is especially common (in my experience) with local network names in Chrome.

I find that simply sticking a `/` on the end of the address helps the browser decide what to do.

Comment: mozilla directly adds `/` to the search string like localhost (only server names)